# Flutter WebRTC There is no sound in the call

Tags: flutter, webrtc, stun

I'm building an application that provides voice conversation with Flutter and WebRTC. When I initiate a call with WebRTC, no sound is sent in a voice call.

I use STUN server for P2P and privacy. A connection is established with the STUN server and I am receiving candidate data. There is no mutual voice conversation only. I know STUN server has problems with ports and firewalls. I am sure my problem is not caused by this.

Before writing here, I thought to issue an issue to the [WebRTC repo on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc), but unfortunately the repo is quite passive. I could not even get an answer to the issue I opened 2 weeks ago([About sound effects](https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc/issues/444)).

I share the dart file with the voice conversation. I would be very happy if you could give an idea. I could not find a solution. Thank you for sparing your precious time.

**My code: [call_page.dart](https://pastebin.pl/view/embed/)**

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: No. I couldnt find it